# Display multiple divs on the same line using css (navigation menu)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, footer

I have a footer menu I am creating for WordPress. I have my main navigation links then at the end I want a collapsing/expanding link for social icons. I have created both separately but do not know how to make them display on one line. Any help is appreciated.

**Main Navigation:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#footernav {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#footernav li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="footernav">
  <li><a href="#hi">Customer Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="#hi">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Expanding/Collapsing Social Link:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

/*SOCIAL*/
.list {
    display:none; 
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    float: center;
}
.show {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target + .show {
    display: inline; 
}
.hide:target {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target ~ .list {
    display:inline; 
}
.hide:hover, .show:hover {
    color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.list p {
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    .hover:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000
}
/*END SOCIAL*/
   </style>

<div class='social'>
    <a href="#show" class="hide" id="show" style="  font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif; font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">Follow Us (+)</a>
    <a href="#hide" class="show" id="show" style="  font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif; font-size: 14px;font-weight:bold;">Follow Us (-)</a>

<div class="list">
<p>
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target= "_blank" ><img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Facebook1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Facebook.png'" ></a> 

 <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target= "_blank1" ><img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Twitter.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Twitter1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Twitter.png'"  ></a> 

 <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target= "_blank2" ><img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram.png'" ></a> 
</p>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/7j0nb4az/

Comment: better provide a fiddle , if you really need help.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle or provide a link to your website.

Comment: Added fiddle to main post. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Flashbond/7j0nb4az/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're missing the `<ul>` tag wrapped around your `<li>`'s inside the jsFiddle. Secondly, once you wrap the `<li>`'s with a `<ul>` tag, adding this CSS to your stylesheet will solve the issue:

```
#footernav ul {
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```css
/*MAIN NAVIGATION*/

#footernav {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#footernav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
#footernav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footernav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a#show {
  vertical-align: top;
}
#footernav li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
a.hide {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
/*END MAIN NAVIGATION*/

/*SOCIAL*/

.list {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  float: center;
}
.show {
  display: none;
}
.hide:target + .show {
  display: block;
}
.hide:target {
  display: none;
}
.hide:target ~ .list {
  display: inline;
}
.hide:hover,
.show:hover {
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.list p {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  .hover: hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div id="footernav" class="footernav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#hi">Customer Care</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#hi">Privacy Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Terms</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <div class='social'> <a href="#show" class="hide" id="show" style="  font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif; font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">Follow Us (+)</a>
          <a href="#hide" class="show" id="show" style="  font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif; font-size: 14px;font-weight:bold;">Follow Us (-)</a>

          <div class="list" <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Facebook1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Facebook.png'">
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank1">
              <img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Twitter.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Twitter1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Twitter.png'">
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank2">
              <img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram.png'">
            </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hello. That worked great at making it inline. However, I was wondering how I can remove the dotted lines under the links? Also how can I make the icons appear underneath the "Follow Us" link as to beside? See it live here http://museiam.ca/. Thanks!

Comment: The website shows a coming soon page however I've updated my code snippet above with the requested changes, please check.

Comment: Hey. That worked great. I will accept your answer. However the dotted underline is still there? I removed the coming soon page, please check now. Thanks!

Comment: @crazythedon Adding this CSS to your stylesheet will remove that dotted line: `#footernav li { border-bottom: none !important; }`.

Comment: Sorry again- But I noticed the onmouseover attribute(for hover) no longer works? Ay idea why?

Comment: @crazythedon On which element?

Comment: For the social icons in the social menu. I used the html attibute onmouseover to create the hover but it seems to no longer work. Appreciate any input. Thx.

Comment: @crazythedon I reviewed your source code and the syntax which you're using for onmouseover and onmouseout is incorrect. This is the code which you should use: `<img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" />`

Comment: Hello. Correct me if I am wrong but I am using the same syntax. Anyhow, I still copied in yours with the correct urls and still no luck :(

Comment: Also, you cant click the icon for some reason, even though it has a link?

Comment: @crazythedon The links work fine for me. The first facebook icone isn't linked to any URL which is why clicking on it doesn't open any link. Secondly, remove the `?a360de` part from your image URL's. As an example, try using this code for the instagram icon: `<img src="http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/Instagram.png'">`